# Either you do not have a card saved to your Wallet or the current domain is not registered for Apple Pay

Tags: php, stripe-payments, applepay, applepay-web

I'm trying to set up Apple Pay using Stripe on my website.

I'm following the instructions here https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

I've already registered my domain on Stripe, seen here

[image]

Then i added test card to my wallet on my macbook, seen here

[image]

When i run ngrok on my localhost, ngrok shows me this

```
ngrok                                                                                                                 (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                      
Hello World! https://ngrok.com/next-generation                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                      
Session Status                online                                                                                                  
Account                       XXXXXXX (Plan: Pro)                                                                                    
Version                       3.0.6                                                                                                   
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                      
Latency                       302ms                                                                                                   
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                   
Forwarding                    https://XXXXXXXXXX.ngrok.io -> https://blabla.xxxxx.com:443                                           
                                                                                                                                      
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                             
                              91      0       0.01    0.01    5.03    9.41                                                            
                                                                                                                                      
HTTP Requests                                                                                                                         
-------------                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                      
GET /frontend/web/debug/default/toolbar    200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/payment/checkout/ 200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/debug/default/toolbar    200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/payment/checkout/ 200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/debug/default/toolbar    200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/payment/checkout/ 200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/debug/default/toolbar    200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/payment/checkout/ 200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/debug/default/toolbar    200 OK                                                                                     
GET /frontend/web/payment/checkout/ 200 OK
```

**When i view my site through the ngrok domain on Safari**, i get this error on the safari console

```
Either you do not have a card saved to your Wallet or the current domain (XXXXXXXX.ngrok.io) is not registered for Apple Pay. Visit https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apple_pay to register this domain.
```

I'm using stripe php and stripe.js for my payment. Here is my JS

```
var publishableKey = document.getElementById('payment-form').getAttribute('data-stripe-publishable-key');
var paymentIntent = document.getElementById('payment-form').getAttribute('data-stripe-paymentIntent');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    if (!publishableKey) {
        document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = 'No publishable key returned from the server';
    }
  
    // 1. Initialize Stripe
    const stripe = Stripe(publishableKey, {
      apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
    });
  
    // 2. Create a payment request object
    var paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
      country: 'US',
      currency: 'usd',
      total: {
        label: 'Demo total',
        amount: 1999,
      },
      requestPayerName: true,
      requestPayerEmail: true,
    });
  
    // 3. Create a PaymentRequestButton element
    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
      paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
    });
  
    // Check the availability of the Payment Request API,
    // then mount the PaymentRequestButton
    paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function (result) {
      if (result) {
        prButton.mount('#applepay-element');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('applepay-element').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = 'Apple Pay support not found. Check the pre-requisites above and ensure you are testing in a supported browser.';
      }
    });
  
paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', async (e) => {
      // Confirm the PaymentIntent without handling potential next actions (yet).
      let {error, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
        clientSecret,
        {
          payment_method: e.paymentMethod.id,
        },
        {
          handleActions: false,
        }
      );
  
      if (error) {
        document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = error.message;

        // Report to the browser that the payment failed, prompting it to
        // re-show the payment interface, or show an error message and close
        // the payment interface.
        e.complete('fail');
        return;
      }
      // Report to the browser that the confirmation was successful, prompting
      // it to close the browser payment method collection interface.
      e.complete('success');
  
      // Check if the PaymentIntent requires any actions and if so let Stripe.js
      // handle the flow. If using an API version older than "2019-02-11" instead
      // instead check for: `paymentIntent.status === "requires_source_action"`.
      if (paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action') {
        // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow.
        let {error, paymentIntent} = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
          clientSecret
        );
        if (error) {
            // The payment failed -- ask your customer for a new payment method.
            document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = error.message;
          return;
        }
        document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = 'Payment ${paymentIntent.status}: ${paymentIntent.id}';
      }
  
      document.getElementById('applepay-error').textContent = 'Payment ${paymentIntent.status}: ${paymentIntent.id}';
    });
  });
```

Any idea how get this to work? Thank you.

Comment: So do you have a card saved to your Wallet?

Comment: @Vincent yup, as shown in the image

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons you want to double check:

1. Domain was set up in a different Stripe Account than the Publishable Key's owner account.
2. Issue with a specific Apple account.
3. If this involves Stripe Connect and Standard/Direct Charge it would be more complicated.

You can double check 1), ask your friend or colleague for help on checking 2). If that doesn't help, write to Stripe Support and they would be able to help checking further on 3).